# The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 530)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, qsqlquery

I am using below query to identify blocking on server and send an alert also kill the session (executing via SQL Job).
Query is using 2 CET table Blcokers and Hierarchy.

Many times I am getting below error and the job fails.

**Error:**
NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 32767 has been exhausted before statement completion. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 530).  The step failed.

On research I found to use  OPTION(MAXRECURSION) HINT in the query to avid the error.
I have included the HINT for Hierarchy CET table as per below but still getting same error

**SELECT * INTO #BlockingProcess
FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)**

Can some one please suggest me what changes should I make in the below code to stop the infinite recursion.

******ENITER CODE:******

```
SET nocount ON; 
SET concat_null_yields_null OFF 
go


CREATE TABLE #sp_who2(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    SPID VARCHAR(4),
    Status VARCHAR(200),
    Login VARCHAR(200),
    HostName  VARCHAR(200),
    BlkBy VARCHAR(4),
    DBName VARCHAR(200),
    Command VARCHAR(200),
    CPUTime VARCHAR(20),
    DiskIO VARCHAR(20),
    LastBatch VARCHAR(20),
    ProgramName VARCHAR(200),
    SPID2 VARCHAR(4),
    RequestID VARCHAR(4)
)

INSERT #sp_who2
EXEC sp_who2

--SELECT SPID, BlkBy FROM #sp_who2
DELETE FROM #sp_who2
 WHERE BlkBy='  .'
   AND SPID NOT IN (SELECT BlkBy FROM #sp_who2 WHERE BlkBy IS NOT NULL)

;WITH Hierarchy(ChildSPID,Generation,BlkBy)
AS
(
    SELECT SPID, 0, BlkBy
      FROM #sp_who2 AS FirtGeneration
     WHERE BlkBy='  .'       
     UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.SPID, Parent.Generation+1, Parent.ChildSPID
      FROM #sp_who2 AS NextGeneration
            INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.BlkBy = Parent.ChildSPID    
)
SELECT * INTO #BlockingProcess
  FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)

SELECT * FROM #BlockingProcess

--loop and kill lead blockers
DECLARE @SPIDGen0           INT
DECLARE @SPIDGen1           INT
DECLARE @ElapsedTimeMSGen0  INT  --if NULL, use Gen1
DECLARE @ElapsedTimeMSGen1  INT
DECLARE @SUBJECTKILL            VARCHAR(200);
--DECLARE @tableHTMLKILL            NVARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE BlkBy='  .')
BEGIN
    SELECT @SPIDGen0=MIN(ChildSPID) FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE Generation=0
    SELECT @SPIDGen1=MIN(ChildSPID) FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE Generation=1 and BlkBy=@SPIDGen0
    PRINT @SPIDGen0
    PRINT @SPIDGen1

    SELECT @ElapsedTimeMSGen0 = BlockingRequest.total_elapsed_time
      FROM sys.dm_exec_requests BlockingRequest
     WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen0

    SELECT @ElapsedTimeMSGen1 = BlockingRequest.total_elapsed_time
      FROM sys.dm_exec_requests BlockingRequest
     WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen1
     
    PRINT @ElapsedTimeMSGen0
    PRINT @ElapsedTimeMSGen1

--If (select count(*) from #BLOCKERS) >= 1
IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1) >= 120000
begin
DECLARE @Subject varchar(100)
SELECT @Subject = 'Blocking Tree Report from ' +  @@servername
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @body = @tableHTML
        ,@body_format = 'HTML'
        ,@profile_name = N''
        ,@recipients = N''
       
        ,@Subject = @Subject      
end

drop table #BLOCKERS

WAITFOR DELAY '00:03'

IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1)>180000 --milliseconds = 3 minutes
    --IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1)>60000 --milliseconds = 3 minutes
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SUBJECTKILL=@@SERVERNAME+' - Lead Blocker Session '+CAST(@SPIDGen0 AS VARCHAR(5))+' Killed'
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name='',
            @recipients='',
        
            @subject = @SUBJECTKILL,
            @body = @tableHTML,
            @body_format = 'HTML'

        EXEC('KILL ' + @SPIDGen0)
    END
    --Skip current SPID and move to next SPID
    DELETE FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE ChildSPID = @SPIDGen0
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sp_who2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #sp_who2
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BlockingProcess') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BlockingProcess
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; you're hitting the maximum number of recursions. Also, why are you using `NOLOCK` against **every** table object? "NOLOCK" isn't a magic "go faster button"; [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). What are you actually trying to achieve here? There's a lot of code for us to go through there, so though it may reproduce the problem, it's not a [mre].

Comment: Hi, I query is capturing Blocking sessions onto Hierarchy CET table and kill the blocker. This is used by the DBA to control blocking on server. NO LOCK is used because this is a maintenance query and this should not block any production sessions.

Comment: You might want to try to change maxrecursion to 0 - as far as I remember this solves the problem BUT you might end up with a very long running query...

Comment: You're using a recursive CTE that potentially never completes, hence why specifying `MAXRECURSION` will do you no good. You have failed to exclude the case where BlkBy = SPID, which can happen if tasks are suffering from parallelism blocks -- they will appear to be blocked by themselves. Also, using the undocumented `sp_who2` for this is rather clumsy, I recommend `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` and related views. It's a little more work but you can also query much more detail that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sp_whoisactive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/) instead. It gives pretty human-readable view of what is going on and what process is process or blocking which others.

Also, you can filter the results by running time and kill the slowest.

But, what you are doing does not seem right. You have automation script for killing transaction. What if one is generated invoice report once per month which take 5 minutes and you constantly kill it? What if one is creating an index which blocks transactions on the specified table and you kill it?

There is a reason there is no such functionality by Microsoft - a person needs to take the call.

It will be better to use this routine to identify slow queries and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that in by above query it was somehow exceeding max recursion when a parallel session blocks itself and it should not be considered are blocking.

So, I avoided that parallel sessions by including  OR SPID=BlkBy in below delete statement

```
DELETE FROM #sp_who2
 WHERE BlkBy='  .'
   AND SPID NOT IN (SELECT BlkBy FROM #sp_who2 WHERE BlkBy IS NOT NULL)
```

After this the query started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response.

Apologies for late reply.

I have removed the dependency on CET table since with going into maximum recursion when every the blocking was due to sleeping session and my previous script was not able to identify sleeping session.
I have observed exec_requests dmv does not capture all sleeping sessions and hence some how the script used to reach maximum recursion when there is blocking by sleeping session, since I have Join exec_requests dmv to fetch blocking data.

SOLUTION:
I have replace CET with Temp Table and also replaced  exec_requests dmv with sys.sysprocesses system table. This solved the max recursion issue.

Also, I have added some more filters to kill blocking for sleeping session.
So, now the query kills head blocker if it is an active session and blocking more than 3 min OR if head blocker  is a sleeping session.

Below is the modified full query for your reference. I am sure there will many modification required, please provide suggestions if any.

```
SET nocount ON;
SET concat_null_yields_null OFF
go

WITH blockers (spid, blocked, level, batch, lastwaittype, status,hostname,cmd,DBNAME,loginname,open_tran,login_time)
     AS (SELECT spid,
                blocked,

                Cast (Replicate ('0', 4-Len (Cast (spid AS VARCHAR)))
                      + Cast (spid AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR (1000))         AS
                LEVEL,
                Replace (Replace (T.text, Char(10), ' '), Char (13), ' ') AS
                BATCH,
                R.lastwaittype,
R.status,
                R.hostname,r.cmd,DB_NAME(r.dbid),r.loginame,r.open_tran,r.login_time
         FROM   sys.sysprocesses R WITH (nolock)
                CROSS apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(R.sql_handle) T
         WHERE  ( blocked = 0
                   OR blocked = spid )
                AND EXISTS (SELECT spid,
                                   blocked,
                                   Cast (Replicate ('0', 4-Len (Cast (spid AS
                                         VARCHAR
                                         )))
                                         + Cast (spid AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR (
                                         1000))
                                   AS
                                       LEVEL,
                                   blocked,
                                   Replace (Replace (T.text, Char(10), ' '),
                                   Char (13
                                   ),
                                   ' ') AS
                                       BATCH,
                                   R.lastwaittype,
  R.status,
                                    R.hostname,r.cmd,DB_NAME(r.dbid),r.loginame,r.open_tran,r.login_time
                            FROM   sys.sysprocesses R2 WITH (nolock)
                                   CROSS apply
                                   sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(R.sql_handle) T
                            WHERE  R2.blocked = R.spid
                                   AND R2.blocked <> R2.spid
                                   AND DB_NAME(r.dbid) NOT IN ('msdb'))
         UNION ALL
         SELECT R.spid,
                R.blocked,
                Cast (blockers.level
                      + RIGHT (Cast ((1000 + R.spid) AS VARCHAR (100)), 4) AS
                      VARCHAR
                      (
                      1000)) AS
                LEVEL,
                Replace (Replace (T.text, Char(10), ' '), Char (13), ' ')
                AS BATCH,
                R.lastwaittype,
R.status,
                R.hostname ,r.cmd,DB_NAME(r.dbid),r.loginame,r.open_tran,r.login_time
         FROM   sys.sysprocesses AS R WITH (nolock)
                CROSS apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(R.sql_handle) T
                INNER JOIN blockers
                        ON R.blocked = blockers.spid
         WHERE  R.blocked > 0
                AND R.blocked <> R.spid
                AND DB_NAME(r.dbid) NOT IN ('msdb'))
SELECT N''
       + Replicate (N'|.......', Len (level)/4 - 2)
       + CASE WHEN (Len (level)/4 - 1) = 0 THEN 'HEAD - ' ELSE '|------ ' END +
       Cast (
       spid AS VARCHAR (10)) + ' ' + batch AS BLOCKING_TREE,
  Spid,
  blocked,
       hostname,
  Status,
       lastwaittype, cmd,DBNAME,loginname,open_tran,login_time,
       Getdate()                           AS 'RunTime' ,
       level
 --(Select convert(varchar, total_elapsed_time /60000 ) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), (total_elapsed_time /1000) % 60 ),2 )   from sys.dm_Exec_requests) as StartedSince
INTO  #BLOCKERS
FROM   blockers WITH (nolock)
ORDER  BY level ASC


--select * from #BLOCKERS

    DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @tableHTML = N'<H1>Blocking Tree Report</H1>' + N'<table border="1" bordercolor="#ff0000" cellspacing="0">' + N'<tr>' +
    N'<th>Blocking_Tree</th>' + N'<th>hostname</th>' + N'<th>Status</th>' + N'<th>lastwaittype</th>'+'<th>CurrentTime</th>'
    + N'<th>cmd</th>'
    + N'<th>DatabaseName</th>'
    + N'<th>loginname</th>'
    + N'<th>open_tran</th>'
    + N'<th>login_time</th>'
    + '</tr>' + CAST((
SELECT td = Blocking_Tree,'',
         td =hostname,'',
td =Status,'',
         td =lastwaittype,'',
         td =RunTime,'',
         td= cmd,'',
         td= DBNAME,'',
         td= loginname,'',
         td=open_tran,'',
         td=login_time,''
         FROM #BLOCKERS
             order by level asc
FOR XML PATH('tr')
                    ,TYPE
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</table>';  

----------------------------------------------------------------

Insert Into  [TOOLS].[dbo].[Lead_Blocker_Log]
select  * from  #BLOCKERS
------------------------------------------------------

SELECT * INTO #BlockingProcess
  FROM #BLOCKERS


  --select * from #BlockingProcess

---------------------------------------------------------
  --loop and kill lead blockers
--DECLARE @SPIDGen2 INT
DECLARE @SPIDGen0 INT
DECLARE @SPIDGen1 INT
DECLARE @ElapsedTimeMSGen0 INT  --if NULL, use Gen1
DECLARE @ElapsedTimeMSGen1 INT
DECLARE @SUBJECTKILL VARCHAR(200)
Declare @sleeping1 VARCHAR (50)
Declare @sleeping2 VARCHAR (50)
--DECLARE @tableHTMLKILL NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE Blocked NOt in ('0') )
Begin

    SELECT @SPIDGen0=MIN(SPID) FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE Blocked=0
SELECT @SPIDGen1=MIN(SPID) FROM #BlockingProcess WHERE lastwaittype = 'LCK_M_U'
    --PRINT @SPIDGen0
---PRINT @SPIDGen1


SELECT @ElapsedTimeMSGen0 = BlockingRequest.total_elapsed_time
 FROM sys.dm_exec_requests BlockingRequest
WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen0

SELECT @ElapsedTimeMSGen1 = BlockingRequest.total_elapsed_time
 FROM sys.dm_exec_requests BlockingRequest
WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen1

--PRINT @ElapsedTimeMSGen0
--PRINT @ElapsedTimeMSGen1

SELECT @sleeping1 = BlockingRequest.status
 FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions BlockingRequest
WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen0

SELECT @sleeping2 = BlockingRequest.status
 FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions BlockingRequest
WHERE session_id=@SPIDGen1

--PRINT @sleeping1
--PRINT @sleeping2


If (select count(*) from #BLOCKERS) > 1
IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1) >180000 OR  ISNULL (@sleeping1,@sleeping2) = 'sleeping'
begin
DECLARE @Subject varchar(100)
SELECT @Subject = 'Blocking Tree Report from ' +  @@servername
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @body = @tableHTML
        ,@body_format = 'HTML'
        ,@profile_name = N'DBMailProfile'
      
   ,@Subject = @Subject      
end


IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1)>180000 OR  ISNULL (@sleeping1,@sleeping2) = 'sleeping'--milliseconds = 3 minutes
--IF ISNULL(@ElapsedTimeMSGen0,@ElapsedTimeMSGen1)>60000 --milliseconds = 3 minutes
BEGIN

EXEC ('KILL ' + @SPIDGen0)

SELECT @SUBJECTKILL=@@SERVERNAME+' - Lead Blocker Session '+CAST(@SPIDGen0 AS VARCHAR(5))+' Killed'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

@subject = @SUBJECTKILL,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'

Print ('KILL ' + Convert (varchar (50),@SPIDGen0))

END

END

--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sp_who2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #sp_who2
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BLOCKERS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BLOCKERS
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BlockingProcess') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #BlockingProcess
```